# Golang unittest http handler

Tags: unit-testing, go

I want to make a simple server that can receive web hook requests from services and deal with them for me. And for fun I wanted to build that in Go, since that sounds like a nice language and this is a simple project to start with.

The server seems to be working fine, but I can't get my unittest to work. On inspection it seems that every url gives a 404. What am I doing wrong?

*main.go*

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func pingHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "{\"check\": \"online\"}")
}

func main() {
    // Start server
    log.Print("Starting server")
    http.HandleFunc("/ping", pingHandler)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":7080", nil))
}
```

*main_test.go*

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "testing"
)

func TestPingHandler(t *testing.T) {
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "/ping", nil)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    rr := httptest.NewRecorder()
    http.DefaultServeMux.ServeHTTP(rr, req)

    status := rr.Code
    fmt.Println(status)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your handler is registered in `main`, but `main` is not invoked when you're running unit tests. So, when you try to test via `DefaultMux`, no handlers are registered, and you get a 404. However, generally you test the handler, not the mux; so instead of this line:

```
http.DefaultServeMux.ServeHTTP(rr, req)
```

You would instead test:

```
pingHandler(rr, req)
```

Which will work even though `main` is not executed to register the handler, because you're now testing the handler directly.

You should also use [`httptest.NewRequest`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#NewRequest) to create requests for testing; `http.NewRequest` is for creating requests for use in a `Client`.